# What is the mistake in my reasoning in calculating limit where $x \to -\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

I had this question in an exam today:

$$
\lim \limits_{x \, \to \,-\infty} \; \frac{\sqrt{x^2+4x}-2x}{2x}
$$

My question is: I have tried to solve it and I also found two other methods to solve it, one in my textbook and one from somebody else. All three methods give different answers, and I can't see the issue with either of the methods which are not mine. I need help figuring out what the invalid operation(s) in each of the wrong methods are, and which 2 (or 3) methods are wrong.

I didn't solve it in the exam, but afterwards tried this:

$$
\lim \limits_{x \, \to \,-\infty} \; \frac{\sqrt{x^2+4x}-2x}{2x} \\
= \; \lim \limits_{x \, \to \,-\infty} \; \Bigg(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4x}}{2x}\Bigg)  - 1 \\
= \; \frac{1}{2}\lim \limits_{x \, \to \,-\infty} \; \Bigg(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4x}}{x}\Bigg)  - 1 \\
= \; \frac{1}{2}\lim \limits_{x \, \to \,-\infty} \; \Big(\sqrt{x^2+4x}\cdot \frac{1}{x}\Big)  - 1 \\
= \; \frac{1}{2} \; \Big(\lim \limits_{x \, \to \,-\infty}\sqrt{x^2+4x} \, \cdot \, \lim \limits_{x \, \to \,-\infty}\frac{1}{x}\Big)  - 1 \\
= \; \frac{1}{2} \; \Bigg(\sqrt{\lim \limits_{x \, \to \,-\infty}x^2+4x}\,\cdot \, \lim \limits_{x \, \to \,-\infty}\frac{1}{x}\Bigg)  - 1 \\
= \; \frac{1}{2} \; \Bigg(\sqrt{\lim \limits_{x \, \to \,-\infty}x^2+4x}\,\cdot \, 0\Bigg)  - 1 \\
= \; -1 \\
$$

I understand my mistake: I multiply an infinite amount with 0 and say it is equal to 0 in my last step.

However, our study guide has that exact example with the following solution:

$$
\lim \limits_{x \, \to \,-\infty} \; \frac{\sqrt{x^2+4x}-2x}{2x} \\
= \; \lim \limits_{x \, \to \,-\infty} \; \frac{\sqrt{x^2(1+\frac{4}{x})}-2x}{2x} \\
= \; \lim \limits_{x \, \to \,-\infty} \; \frac{|x|\sqrt{(1+\frac{4}{x})}-2x}{2x} \\
= \; \lim \limits_{x \, \to \,-\infty} \; \frac{-x\sqrt{(1+\frac{4}{x})}-2x}{2x} \; ; \; (x < 0) \\
= \; \lim \limits_{x \, \to \,-\infty} \; \frac{-x(\sqrt{(1+\frac{4}{x})}+2)}{2x} \\
= \; \lim \limits_{x \, \to \,-\infty} \; \frac{-(\sqrt{(1+\frac{4}{x})}+2)}{2} \\
= \; \frac{-\Bigg(\sqrt{\lim \limits_{x \, \to \,-\infty} \; (1+\frac{4}{x})}+2\Bigg)}{2} \\
= \; \frac{-(\sqrt{1+0}+2)}{2} \\
= \; \frac{-(\sqrt{1}+2)}{2} \\
= \; \frac{-(1+2)}{2} \\
= \; -\frac{3}{2}
$$

To complicate matters even more: someone else solved the problem like this and got a third answer:

$$
\lim \limits_{x \, \to \,-\infty} \; \frac{\sqrt{x^2+4x}-2x}{2x} \\
= \; \lim \limits_{x \, \to \,-\infty} \; \frac{\sqrt{x^2+4x}}{2x} - 1 \\
= \; \lim \limits_{x \, \to \,-\infty} \; \sqrt{\frac{x^2+4x}{4x^2}} - 1 \\
= \; \lim \limits_{x \, \to \,-\infty} \; \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{x}} - 1 \\
= \; \; \sqrt{\lim \limits_{x \, \to \,-\infty} \; \Big(\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{x}\Big)} - 1 \\
= \; \sqrt{\lim \limits_{x \, \to \,-\infty} \; \frac{1}{4} + \lim \limits_{x \, \to \,-\infty} \; \frac{1}{x}} - 1 \\
= \; \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} + 0} - 1 \\
= \; \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}} - 1 \\
= \; \frac{1}{2} - 1 \\
= \; -\frac{1}{2}
$$

Comment: When $x$ is negative, $\sqrt{4x^2}$ is not $2x$

Comment: The first derivation is wrong: Substituting the limit of a product with the product of limits is invalid if it yields 0 * infinity (but it would be valid if both limits were finite). It is also invalid to assume that limit(something) * 0 is zero, unless the limit in question is finite.

Comment: A common mistake with even-roots in limits going to "negative infinity" is forgetting that for negative $ \ x \ \ , \ \ \sqrt{x^2} \ = \ | x | \ = \ -x \ \ . $  So in the third derivation, for instance, bringing the $ \ 2x \ $ in the denominator under the square-root as $ \ 4x^2 \ $ requires that a "minus-sign" now be affixed to the square-root.  That will then lead to $ \ -\frac12 \ - \ 1 \ \ . $  What is done in the second method correctly handles this issue.

Comment: You can't substitutel $\lim M(x)N(x)$ with $\lim M(x)\cdot \lim N(x)$ unless $\lim M(x), \lim N(x)$ are bounded.  If one is unbounded and the other non-zero then we can conclude the result is unbounded but if one is $0$ and the other unbounded all bets are off.  The study guide did no such thing.  If did $\lim F(G(x)) = F(\lim G(x))$ which is fine if $F$ is continuous and $\lim G(x)$ is finite.  ... The third ones only mistake is that if $x < 0$ then $2x = -\sqrt{4x^2}$ and not $2x=\sqrt{4x^2}$.  Thus lime is $-\frac 12 - 1 =-\frac 32$.  Which is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Exact explanations were made about the mistake you made in the comments. You missed that $x$ is negative.

You can observe this simple fact:

$$\begin{align}x=\begin{cases}-\sqrt{x^2},~\text{if}~ x<0\\\sqrt{x^2}, ~\text{if}~x>0\end{cases}\end{align}$$

This immediately reveals your mistake.

I would calculate this limit as follows:

$$\begin{align}\lim \limits_{x\to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+4x}-2x}{2x}&=-\lim_{x \to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2-4x}+2x}{2x}\\
&=-\lim_{x \to\infty} \left(\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{4x^2}-\frac{4x}{4x^2}}+1\right)\\
&=-\lim_{x \to\infty} \left(\sqrt{\frac 14-\frac{1}{x}}+1\right)\\
&=-\left(\frac 12+1\right)\\
&=-\frac 32.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

As noticed the second method is the correct one, to check the result we can make the limit simpler at positive $\infty$ by $u=-x\to \infty$, then

$$\lim \limits_{x \, \to \,-\infty} \; \frac{\sqrt{x^2+4x}-2x}{2x} =\lim \limits_{u \, \to \,\infty} \; \frac{\sqrt{u^2-4u}+2u}{-2u}=\lim \limits_{u \, \to \,\infty} \; \frac{\sqrt{1-\frac4 u}+2}{-2}=-\frac 3 2$$